# Как запустить скрипт python на странице

Tags: python

Заранее извиняюсь возможно глупый вопрос, хочу начать писать на питоне, до этого писал только на PHP.

Подскажите, как я могу интегрировать код на пайтоне в страницу. К примеру на PHP достаточно в любой части странице написать:

```
<?PHP echo 'Hello world'?>
```

Как это делается на питоне? Я добавил на страницу index.html код на питоне:

```
import cgi
print('Hello world')
```

Когда открываю index.html вместо **Hello world** получаю **import cgi print('Hello world')**

Почему код не исполняется?

Answer (score 1):

Используй py-script (https://pyscript.net)
Подключаем js script в head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
```

После этого появляется возможность пользоваться тегом :

```
<py-script> print('Now you can!') </py-script>
```

Используй py-script в body

Answer (score 0):

Для начала необходимо в настройках web сервера( Apache, nginx) указать настройки исполнения cgi. Указать алиас для URL и каталог где находятся сами скрипты.
Вот пример настроек для апача 
http://dedicatesupport.com/content/nastroika-vypolneniya-cgi-skriptov-v-apache-20

Answer (score 0):

Наряду с CGI Python на сервере можно запустить также средствами PHP. Все очень просто:

**script.py**

```
print("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('python3 script.py');
echo $output;
?>
```

Разумеется, Python должен быть установлен. И почитайте [вот это](https://zalinux.ru/?p=8426). Тут речь идет о передаче скрипту данных.

**UPD:**
А [**вот**](https://zalinux.ru/?p=8413) хороший туториал про настройку Python-а в виде CGI...Главное не забыть указать в начале скрипта путь, например, `#!/usr/bin/python3` и отправлять  header через `print("Content-type: text/html\n")`.